# Change terminal window background color and text

Tags: bash, terminal

At the moment I have this in a file called **show_error_logs.sh**

```
osascript <<END
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd /vagrant" in window 1
    do script "vagrant ssh" in window 1
    do script "sudo su" in window 1
    do script "cd /var/log/apache2/" in window 1
    do script "tail -f error.log" in window 1
end tell
END
```

This runs when I type **show-errors** as I set this up in my alias.

At the moment it is working great, but I just want to theme it a little. I would like the background color to be black and the main text white.

Also, if it is possible, I would like specific text to be a different color. For example, `PHP Fatal error` I would like to have a background color of red.

Comment: This is dependent on the terminal. However, most terminal emulators understand basic [XTerm control sequences](http://www.xfree86.org/4.5.0/ctlseqs.html). For example, `echo -e '\e[31mRed text\e[0m Normal text'` will display "Red text" as dark red in most terminal emulators, including obviously XTerm, Gnome Terminal, Linux virtual consoles and Windows console windows (when used with Ubuntu on Windows). So after `tail -f error.log` add `| sed -e '...'` and replace `...` so that specific patterns are colored. Take care with quoting special characters, you have multiple levels of interpretation.

Comment: @AlexP thank for ur reply. when I put `do script "tail -f error.log | sed -e '\e[31mRed text\e[0m Normal text'" in window 1` - I get the error `226:227: syntax error: Expected “"” but found unknown token. (-2741)`

Comment: @AlexP my terminal is just the standard mac terminal

Comment: `sed` is a stream editor; you should read the manual page for your system -- try `man sed`. It expects a substitution command of the form `s/findsomething/replacewithsomething/`. My example was an example of a simple shell command, just to demonstrate how to output colored text. It is *not* an example of a `sed` substitution pattern. Moreover, as I said, you have multiple levels of processing; the shell reads the text, then `osascript` (whatever it is) reads the text, then `sed` interprets the command: take care with metacharacters.